# Cannot read properties of undefined when in React component but works fine when in getStaticProps function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to create a blog with Node.js, React and graphql. I'm new to all those technologies (including Java-/Typescript itself). I'd greatly appreciate your help.
Currently I'm stuck getting the data of my articles to show.
In the function getStaticProps I can read the data of my graphql response fine.
But when I pass that data as a parameter to the React component (as getStaticProps provides that data during build-time) I can't access that data anymore and get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'articles')".

Below is my code:

```
import {GetStaticProps} from "next";
import {serverSideTranslations} from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import {ssrGetBlog} from "../../generated/page";

// @ts-ignore implicitly has any type
export default function Index(data) {
    console.log(data.attributes) //TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'articles')
                                 // below in getStaticProps this worked!?

    return (
        <div className="relative bg-gray-50 px-4 pt-16 pb-20 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 lg:pt-24 lg:pb-28">
            <div className="absolute inset-0">
                <div className="h-1/3 bg-white sm:h-2/3"/>
            </div>
            <div className="relative mx-auto max-w-7xl">
                <div className="text-center">
                    <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl">
                        {data.blogHeading}
                    </h2>
                    <p className="mx-auto mt-3 max-w-2xl text-xl text-gray-500 sm:mt-4">
                        {data.blogDescription}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="mx-auto mt-12 grid max-w-lg gap-5 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-3">
                    {data.attributes.articles.data.map((article) => (
                        <div
                            key={article.attributes.title}
                            className="flex flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg"
                        >
                            <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                                <img
                                    className="h-48 w-full object-cover"
                                    src={article.attributes.articleImg.data.attributes.url}
                                    alt=""
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex flex-1 flex-col justify-between bg-white p-6">
                                <div className="flex-1">
                                    <p className="text-sm font-medium text-indigo-600">
                                        <a href={"not implemented: article.attributes.articleCategory.data.attributes.slug"} className="hover:underline">
                                            {"none existent: article.attributes.articleCategory.data.attributes.categoryName"}
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <a href={article.attributes.slug} className="mt-2 block">
                                        <p className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900">
                                            {article.attributes.title}
                                        </p>
                                        <p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500">
                                            {article.attributes.shortDescription}
                                        </p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-6 flex items-center">
                                    <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                                        <a href={"not implemented: article.attributes.author.href"}>
                                            <span className="sr-only">{"not implemented: article.author.authorName"}</span>
                                            <img
                                                className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                                                src={"not implemented: article.attributes.author.authorImg"}
                                                alt=""
                                            />
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="ml-3">
                                        <p className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                            <a href={"not implemented: article.attributes.author.authorUrl"} className="hover:underline">
                                                {"not implemented: article.attributes.author.name"}
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        <div className="flex space-x-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                            <time dateTime={article.attributes.publishedOn}>{article.attributes.publishedOn}</time>
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&middot;</span>
                                            <span>{"not implemented: article.attributes.readingTime"} read</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const {locale} = context;

    // @ts-ignore
    const blogQuery = await ssrGetBlog.getServerPage({}, context);
    const data = blogQuery.props.data?.blog?.data; //props.data?.blog?.data?.attributes;
    //console.log(data);  // works fine
    //console.log(data.attributes.articles.data[0]); // works fine
    return {
        props: {
            data,
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale || "", ["common"])),
        },
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, maybe you're not accessing the component's props properly

```js
export default function Index(props) {
    console.log(props.data.attributes)
}
```

or

```js
export default function Index({ data }) {
    console.log(data.attributes)
}
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked! Thanks a lot! I changed nothing but the name of the parameter passed to the Index component from data to props. It seems that it must match the name of the key that's returned by the getStaticProps method.

Comment: It's a javascript thing and it doesn't have to match the name, unless you use the second syntax. You can name the first param anything you like, but it will represent the same object you return in `getStaticProps`. It means if you name the first param of `Index` function as `data`, it will represent an object like this `const data = { data: { attributes } }` so you would need to access it like this: `console.log(data.data.attributes)`. To avoid spaghetti you can just assign the name `props` to it to use `console.log(props.data.attributes)`. Ping me on discord for more info `Vi Sovari#7697`

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
const {locale} = context;

// @ts-ignore
const blogQuery = await ssrGetBlog.getServerPage({}, context);
const data = blogQuery.props.data?.blog?.data; //props.data?.blog?.data?.attributes;
//console.log(data);  // works fine
//console.log(data.attributes.articles.data[0]); // works fine

const comething = await serverSideTranslations(locale || "", ["common"])
return {
    props: {
        data,
        ...comething,
    },
};
```

};

Try this maybe?

Comment: Doesn't change anything for me. Thanks for the suggestion.